# is there any way to play video loaded to memory using vlc python module

Tags: python, video, module, vlc, playback

I am trying to make use of VLC python module to play files after reading them into memory. I have the following code that reads a valid video file into the memory. I need to now play the video directly from the memory.

```
import vlc
File1 = open('vid.webm','rb')
Axel  = File1.read()
```

Now i need to play the contents in Axel, how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the code below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import ctypes
import io
import sys
import time

import vlc

MediaOpenCb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint64))
MediaReadCb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_ssize_t, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char), ctypes.c_size_t)
MediaSeekCb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_uint64)
MediaCloseCb = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p)


def media_open_cb(opaque, data_pointer, size_pointer):
    data_pointer.contents.value = opaque
    size_pointer.contents.value = sys.maxsize
    return 0


def media_read_cb(opaque, buffer, length):
    stream=ctypes.cast(opaque,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.py_object)).contents.value
    new_data = stream.read(length)
    for i in range(len(new_data)):
        buffer[i]=new_data[i]
    return len(new_data)


def media_seek_cb(opaque, offset):
    stream=ctypes.cast(opaque,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.py_object)).contents.value
    stream.seek(offset)
    return 0


def media_close_cb(opaque):
    stream=ctypes.cast(opaque,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.py_object)).contents.value
    stream.close()


callbacks = {
    'open': MediaOpenCb(media_open_cb),
    'read': MediaReadCb(media_read_cb),
    'seek': MediaSeekCb(media_seek_cb),
    'close': MediaCloseCb(media_close_cb)
}

def MediaPlayerTimeChanged(event, userData):
  print event.u.new_time

def main(stream):
    instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = instance.media_player_new()
    vlc_events = player.event_manager()
    vlc_events.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerTimeChanged, MediaPlayerTimeChanged, None)
    media = instance.media_new_callbacks(callbacks['open'], callbacks['read'], callbacks['seek'], callbacks['close'], ctypes.cast(ctypes.pointer(ctypes.py_object(stream)), ctypes.c_void_p))
    player.set_media(media)

    player.play()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        path = "d:/1.mp4"
        stream = open(path, 'rb')
        main(stream)
    except IndexError:
        print('Usage: {0} <path>'.format(__file__))
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Hi. The code is not related to my problem. If you added "stream=stream.read()" after "stream = open(path, 'rb')" , it would be related to my problem.